# Unit Testing AJAX-y UI with Visual Studio

Tags: html, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a UI that is going to leverage HTML 5, css, jquery, and kendo very heavily. Ideally, I'd really like to write tests that simulate a user performing actions. I'm kind of new to this whole unit testing thing. I understand how it works with procedural code. However, I'm not sure how it works with event-based code such as a HTML 5 UI.

Can someone give me some ideas of how to automate testing a HTML UI with visual studio?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CodedUI tests in Visual Studio 2012 to help automate UI tests. With the latest update we have now enabled cross browser testing as well ie you can record these actions on IE and do your testing on IE, Firefox, Chrome

See details here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx